# Is it possible to create one time passwords for full disk encryption on Ubuntu?

Tags: security, ubuntu-16.04, fde

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a one time password system to secure the full disk encryption of a Ubuntu system, such that each login is a unique password and only usable once. I've seen this used as a second factor for auth but I'm looking to make it the only factor for auth. Is this possible? If so, how? Also, is it possible to on top of this use otp as a second factor of auth during ssh?

The idea here is to secure a machine that's in a environment that's likely to attempt to tamper with it, but still allow authorized people to maintain it (but not trust them with a permanent password, only a temporary one that changes for every login). Basically, deny tampering and deny access to someone who might have been maintaining the system and decided to help those trying to tamper with it.